# How to properly manage state with dynamic url routes

Tags: reactjs

Hi i'm trying to implement an app similar to Google Keep with a Sidebar with Two Components

- TagList (For showing Tag names for Notes)
- ColorList (For showing Note Colors)

[image: Sidebar]

as shown above. With following Routes

If **All** is selected (both in tag or color section) **=** no route params

Example Routes

**/**              ( Tag = All , Color = All  )

**/tag/:tag**      ( Tag = :tag , Color = All  )

**/color/:color**  ( Tag = All , Color = :color )

**/tag/:tag/color/:color** ( Tag = :tag , Color = :color  )

I used the following component structure

```
<NoteContextProvider value={this.state}>
       <Topbar />
       <Sidebar />
       <Content>
         <NoteList/>
       </Content>
     </NoteContextProvider>
```

Using the following state shape.

```
      tagsLoaded: false,
      tags: [],
      selectedTag: { id: 0, text: "All" },
      setSelectedTag: (tag) => {
        this.setState({ selectedTag: { ...tag } });
      },
     
      colorsLoaded: false,
      colors: [],
      selectedColor: { id: 0, display: "Default", code: "" },
      setSelectedColor: (color) => {
        this.setState({ selectedColor: { ...color } });
      }
```

and i used Context API to pass these State to all components.

From Sidebar i'm calling **setSelectedTag** or **setSelectedColor** appropriately. It is working fine until i tried to introduce the above URL routing.

**I also wanted to redirect user to **All** in case an invalid Tag/Color is given in url..**

Can anybody suggest a clean approach to achieve the same ?

Comment: Did you check google keep implementation? Check url with difference tags with multi tags. I think google uses query params for this.

Comment: @KirillSkomarovskiy No Google Keep is using Route Params not Query params..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into passing multiple paths to react-router and it will select them in that order. There are a few options you have but you can do something like so:

`<Route path={['/', 'color/:color', 'tag/:tag', '/color:color/tag:tag']} exact>`

You could also consider nesting routers or passing one of the parameters in a querystring.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you please explain how to properly set active state in side bar and where to put Sidebar component..

Comment: Sure! So I would recommend installing react-router and react-router-dom and going through the docs a bit here: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams in order to learn how to pull those parameters :color and :tag from the url using the useParams hook.

In order to set state in the sidebar I would suggest using a NavLink component from react-router-dom. A quick and dirty solution would be something  like: `<NavLink to={\`/tags/${tag ? tag : 'all'}/colors/${color.id}\`}>{color.name}</NavLink>` given you are pulling the tag from the url within that component.

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion. Still I am not sure how we can use NavLink here because Tag need to consider Other (selected Color) and vice versa.. So we need to keep selected Tag/Color in state too or just in Route?

Comment: I would keep it in state (or just have it default to 'all'):

```
`const { tag='all', color='all'} = useParams();`